# What is the Difference between Xamarin and Telerik Platform

Tags: javascript, c#, mobile, xamarin, telerik

This is going to be quite a hectic question and im hoping that you can all Bear with me.

Im having difficulty fully understanding some things about mobile App development.

So my Main question is : What is the difference between Telerik Platform and Xamarin ? Dose it just depending on what you are more comestible with, Like if you are a c# developer and know the .Net framwork, Then use Xamarin or is it alot more complex than that ? As i know that Telerik uses Javascript, so is it more of an open dev based mobile app ?
Which is better for the future of mobile development as i want to move in the right direction.

As an Extra: Has anyone heard of Dart ? i found out about it last week and haven't had much time to Read up on it, but it looks like a web based solution from google.

[Dartlang](https://www.dartlang.org/)

Comment: This is probably too broad, see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi there yea i thought as much, i just am not sure how to slim it down as this is all on my mind for a mobile app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xamarin you can build native applications for Android and iOS system.
It is also possible to write them for Windows Phone.
Xamarin uses C# language.
Apps are created natively using Xamarin wrappers.
There are two options for creating apps in Xamarin:

1) Xamarin.Forms is best for:

- Data entry apps
- Prototypes and proofs-of-concept
- Apps that require little platform-specific functionality
- Apps where code sharing is more important than custom UI

2) Xamarin.iOS & Xamarin.Android are best for:

- Apps that require specialized interactions
- Apps with highly polished design
- Apps that use many platform-specific APIs
- Apps where custom UI is more important than code sharing

Telerik Platform is good for web developers who want to create mobile apps:

- Here you can write html and javascript.
  Remember also that your apps on iOS and Android will be displayed in WebView (browser). Only Windows Phone apps can be written in html and javascript natively.

Hope this will help.

Please also see this (I asked about Xamarin and Apache Cordova):
http://www.codeproject.com/Forums/13695/Mobile.aspx

Comment: Thanks alot man, you hit the Nail on the head, I fully understand now :)

Comment: So now do you know If there are any difference between Telerik platform and the Dart Framwork ? they seem very much the same tomee, just that Dart uses The Dart language that converts to Javascript

Comment: @JodyStocks I don't know the exact difference between those two.
I didn't create an app using them. : (

Comment: No worries man, Um also just a quick on for you, is The telerik platform similer to phoneGap ?

Comment: @JodyStocks Yes it is similar. You can also write html/javascript applications.

Comment: Now telerik has a nativescript which is a close to native app not just a web view (browser)

Answer (score 2):

All of the mentioned framework do the same thing in different ways, its totally depends upon your skillset and interest which framework you find easy to understand or find interesting.

Each of those have their market in which you can grow. below are some links may help you.

http://www.telerik.com/campaigns/build-mobile-apps-with-dotnet

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13686/the-future-benefits-of-xamarin-over-other-options-and-mobile-apps-replacing-websites

Answer (score 0):

[**Dart**](https://www.dartlang.org/) is a modern open source programming language that allows to write concise code

- built-in support for `async`/`await`, `Future` (`Promise`), `Stream` (`Observable`), ...
- Supports lots of platforms

  - Server with the Dart-VM (Windows, OSX, Linux)
  - in the browser after to-JS transpilation
  - Android and iOS by Flutter https://flutter.io/
  - embedded systems by Dartino https://dartino.org/
- Dart can be transpiled to JavaScript (to-TypeScript is work in progress)
- extensive high-quality standard libraries
- `dart:html` library that for browser abstraction that makes most polyfills redundant
- shipped with lots of tools

  - package manager
  - analyzer/linter
  - debugger and profiling tools
  - test runner
  - Dartium development browser
  - ...
- IDE support

  - easy integration using the IDE services the analyzer provides
  - Atom plugin
  - WebStorm/IntelliJ plugin
  - ...